# C# check for node before doing something

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am searching for about one hour now but obviously my search skills are not the best so I have to ask my question here...

Im using htmlAgilityPack and I select some date like this

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc        = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDocTDs     = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDocLink    = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();


htmlDoc.LoadHtml(webBrowser1.DocumentText);

var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("tr").Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("notranslate"));
```

with this I end up in a lot of these here

```
<tr class="notranslate">
    <td class="hideid">1234567</td>
    <td><a href="/xxx/xxx/xxx-x.xxxx.xxx">aaa-a.aaaaaa.aaa</a></td>
    <td class="mobileHide">cccc</td>
    <td>xx.xxx.xxx.xx</td>
    <td>Mar. 03, 2016 3:43 AM</td>
</tr>
```

now to go on, I loop them because I want to get the `innerHtml` of all nodes

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
{
    htmlDocTDs.LoadHtml(node.InnerHtml);
    var tds = htmlDocTDs.DocumentNode.Descendants("td");

    foreach (HtmlNode td in tds)
    {
        htmlDocLink.LoadHtml(td.InnerHtml);
        //... here i got stuck
    }
}
```

now actually I dont want `<a href="..">...</a>` I also want the `innerHtml` of this element. Now what I want to do is to check if the current `td` block has an `a` tag and if yes, get its `innerHtml`.

Since im relative new to C# im not very sure how to do this.

Is this the right way im creating the `htmlDoc` instances?

Is there a possibility to check for node?

Can I select a node without running through a foreach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where to start... first don't parse the `InnerHtml` into a document each time. This is not only highly inefficient, but also unreliable as the `InnerHtml` may have more than one element, which is invalid as HTML or XML document (single rooted). And fragments are not documents anyways.

I'd use XPath to find and select elements, check for specific patterns or extract values from the parsed (main) document. There are plenty of resources for that, just search for `XPath HtmlAgilityPack` here on SO or in Google (I'm not posting links since these may become invalid at any time).

Possible XPath to select the `td` nodes with the same constraint you have defined:

```
//tr[contains(@class,'notranslate')]/td
```

Comment: actually im retrieving a table with some content thats build in the same way every time. and its only once i load the table on programstart because i want to fill a listview in the end. so you think i should go with xpath ?

Comment: XPath is a query language made for markup documents such as XML and HTML. It's short and expresses very well what nodes your code is trying to retrieve and handle, so yes, use it!

Comment: ok, this quite helped my to get rid of some foreach :) but i still have the problem to get `<a href='foo/bar/asdasd'>asdasd</a>` instead of `asdasd`. Still need to check if the content has an A node :)

Comment: but the thing is, obviously i cant use it... because all tds that get selected no come in one foreach. but i need it per row. because i have about 60 rows and i dont want to split an array on every 4th position.